# Solve $(x^2y^2-y)dx+(x+2x^3y)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> solve the following ODE $$(x^2y^2-y)dx+(x+2x^3y)dy=0$$

First I check exactness, $$M=x^2y^2-y,\quad N=x+2x^3y$$
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=2x^2y-1,\quad \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=1+6x^2y$$
$M_y\neq N_x$, hence the ODE is not exact. Then I tried to reduced it to exact DE where I followed,

> $(1)$ If $M$ and $N$ are homogeneous then, IF$=\frac{1}{M_x+N_y};M_x+N_y\neq0$
>   $(2)$ If the DE can be written as $yf_1(x,y)dx+xf_2(x,y)dy=0$ then, IF$=\frac{1}{M_x+N_y};{M_x+N_y}\neq0$
>   $(3)$ If $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}=f(x)\text{ or C}$ then, IF$=e^{\int f(x)dx}$
>   $(4)$ If $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}=f(y)\text{ or C}$ then, IF$=e^{-\int f(y)dy}$
>   Where IF=Integrating factor

But none of these are satisfied. Then how to approach$?$ My professor said that **inspection** maybe a good approach for this one. But I haven't found any. **And How to inspect any ODE$($like this$)$ to guess what to do$?$**

Answer (score 4):

$$(x^2y^2-y)dx+(x+2x^3y)dy=0$$
$$xdy-ydx +x^2(y^2dx+2xydy)=0$$
Divide by $x^2$ 
$$\frac {xdy-ydx}{x^2} +(y^2dx+2xydy)=0$$
$$ {d}\left (\frac {y}{x}\right )+d(y^2x)=0$$
Integrate

Comment: The first term should be $d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$, not $\frac{d}{dx}$, but good solution +1

Comment: @NinadMunshi You are righ thanks. It's corrected.

Comment: But I want to know how did you inspect it @Isham without knowing this solution can't help me a lot

Comment: As your teacher said you need to observe the differential equation before to develop a strategy...@Dr.Antidode

Comment: @Dr.Antidode inspection is math speak for "stare at it until inspiration comes", unfortunately, but there are some clues that this was the approach to take. Whenever you see $xdy-ydx$, it should become second nature for you to recognize that as the derivative of $\frac{y}{x}$. Then that intuition can lead to dividing the whole equation by $x^2$, giving the other term.

Comment: Exactly @NinadMunshi

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh I see. Thanks for response

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by $x^ay^b$, so we want to solve$$\begin{align}(x^{a+2}y^{b+2}-x^ay^{b+1})_y&=(x^{a+1}y^b+2x^{a+3}y^{b+1})_x\\\implies(b+2)x^{a+2}y^{b+1}-(b+1)x^ay^b&=(a+1)x^ay^b+2(a+3)x^{a+2}y^{b+1}\\\implies(b+2,\,-b-1)&=(2a+6,\,a+1)\\\implies(a,\,b)&=(-2,\,0).\end{align}$$So$$0=(y^2-y/x^2)dx+(1/x+2xy)dy=d(xy^2+y/x)\implies x^2y^2-Cx+y=0.$$

Comment: Another good way if someone lost then it will be lifeguard @J.G.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the equation as:

$$x^0y^0((-1)ydx + (1)xdy) + x^2y^1((1)ydx + (2)xdy) = 0$$

There's another rule that says that if a differential equation can be represented in the following form

$$x^ay^b(mydx + nxdy) + x^{a'}y^{b'}(m'ydx + n'xdy) = 0$$

Then, its integrating factor is given by $x^hy^k$, where $h$ and $k$ are given by

$$\frac{a + h + 1}{m} = \frac{b + k + 1}{n}$$

and

$$\frac{a' + h + 1}{m'} = \frac{b' + k + 1}{n'}$$

Therefore, compare the first two equations to get the values and solve the equation to get the values of $h$ and $k$, and hence the integrating factor.

Comment: your answer give $x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ as IF. Which seems not. @Arkajyoti Banerjee Can you kindly demonstrate your answer

Comment: Yeah, I had mistakenly interchanged the positions. Now, it has been corrected. Solving it now gives $h = -2$ and $k = 0$.